# How to select and copy the first 5 rows from a table after applying filters

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy the first 5 rows (to cell M7) after applying a filter in the table. I have tried a macro found on the internet, but it does not work in any way in my file.

```
Sub TopNRows()
Dim i As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim rWC As Range

Set r = Range("B16", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each rWC In r
    i = i + 1
    If i = 5 Or i = r.Count Then Exit For
Next rWC
Range(r(2), rWC).Resize(, 7).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheet7.[M7]
End Sub
```

I tried to customize them, where my table has x rows (I operate dynamically) and 7 columns. The headings are in (B15:H15). However, they do not work all the time. The error pops up for me at

```
Range(r(2), rWC).Resize(, 7).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheet7.[M7]
```

Comment: What is the error?  Where is your text data sample? Why do you not qualify the Range being set with any of your worksheets?  After you set `r`, is the address and worksheet what you expect?

Comment: Error is "Object required"

Comment: Post back after you've responded to my other three questions.

Comment: Data sample is in my active worksheet in Range(B15:H989). I don't qualify Range with any worksheets, because I didn't know that it was needed. After you set r, is the address and worksheet what you expect? If I'm honest, I don't quite know. When trying it on another table of the same size, in another file, it worked, so I thought it would work here too.

Comment: I did not express myself clearly. By "*where is your text data sample*" I meant why have you not posted a sample of your data as text, so we might have a data sample that can be used to help troubleshooting.  You can use this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to properly format the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
Sub TopNRows()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim filt As Range
    Dim topRows As Range
    Dim currentCell As Range
    Dim count As Long
    
    Set rng = Range("B15", Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
    
    With rng
        On Error Resume Next
        Set filt = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If filt Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No records found!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    
    count = 0
    For Each currentCell In filt.Cells
        If topRows Is Nothing Then
            Set topRows = currentCell
        Else
            Set topRows = Union(topRows, currentCell)
        End If
        count = count + 1
        If count >= 5 Then Exit For
    Next currentCell
    
    topRows.Copy Sheet7.[M7]

End Sub
```